# neo4j.test: "package org.neo4j.test does not exist" error in maven

Tags: maven, neo4j

I have small question: when I add dependency

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
       <version>1.8.1</version>
       <type>test-jar</type>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

to maven, I have error:

`package org.neo4j.test does not exist`

Why?

I didn't find "neo4j.test" in maven repository (http://search.maven.org/).

TIA.

---

Eugeny

Comment: Hi, I found the neo4j-kernel-1.8.1-tests.jar at the http://search.maven.org. The link is http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/neo4j/neo4j-kernel/1.8.1/neo4j-kernel-1.8.1-tests.jar Please check at your local repo on your machine that it is loaded already or not. It may be another issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your actual code is underneath `src/main/java`, then the scope should not be `test`. Otherwise, please provide more details.

Comment: Yes, code in `src/main/java`. How I can use test in this case?

Comment: Well, if your code is actually tests, then they should be underneath `src/test/java`. Dependencies with `<scope>test</scope>` will only be available during the compilation and execution of the tests. It won't be available during the compilation of the classes underneath `src/main/java`. I believe this is your error. So -- either move the tests to `src/test/java` or change the scope of the dependency (or just remove it's scope).

Comment: Code under `src/main/java` doesn't see test dependencies. Maven spec.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Maven but I copy the jar from http://m2.neo4j.org/content/groups/everything/org/neo4j/neo4j-kernel/1.8.1/neo4j-kernel-1.8.1-tests.jar

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the classifier element:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
       <version>1.8.1</version>
       <classifier>tests</classifier>
       <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Some read: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates

Comment: This fixed it for me. I've never heard of Maven coordinates before. Alternatively, the probably 'correct' way to do it is to add the `<type>test-jar</type>` to the `dependency>` node, as per the [testing docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html). Now I have problems with the `tooling` package missing, however (`2.0.0 M06`).